# Submit a form based on condition. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and a submit button. I would like to put a condition with jquery on this submit button. I wan't it to post the form only if the user enters a valid email adress.

**HTML code :**

```
<form  method="post" action="{% url sportdub.views.login %}">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="span8"/>
    <input type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

**Javascript code :**

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
```

What I want to do is to put a condition on my submit button:

```
if( !isValidEmailAddress( emailaddress ) ) { 
    /* don't submit the form and raise an error */ 
} else { 
    /* submit the form */
}
```

Any idea on how I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `onsubmit` event handler to your form and `return false` if it don't pass validation.

For example according to your code:

```
  <form  method="post" action="{% url sportdub.views.login %}" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <input type="text" id="formEmail" name="email" value="" class="span8"/>
    <input type="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

in JS:

```
function validateForm() {
    if( !isValidEmailAddress( document.getElementById( 'formEmail' ).value ) ) { 
        // also before return you can add alert( 'your e-mail is invalid' ); 
        // or display message in form, etc...
        return false;
     } else { 
        return true;
     }    
}
```

Btw, I would not recommend to use inline JS attributes, just add to all your elements and to form unique id attribute and if you use jQuery you can do all validations in **[.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)** method.

Comment: @mplungjan This will be not obvious for OP. + maybe he will need to add another validations in future.

Answer (score 3):

Inline:

```
  <form  method="post" action="{% url sportdub.views.login %}"
   onsubmit="return isValidEmailAddress(this.email.value)">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="span8"/>
    <input type="submit"></button>
  </form>
```

Better (plain JS) - note I need an ID of the form:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
    if (!isValidEmailAddress(this.email.value)) {
      alert('Please enter a valid address');
      return false; // cancel submit
    }
    return true; // allow submit
  }
}
```

jQuery version:

```
$(function() {
  $("#form1").on("submit",function(e) {
    if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
      alert('Please enter a valid address');
      return false; // cancel submit
    }
    return true; // allow submit
  });
});
```

Last two assuming

```
<form  id="form1" method="post" action="{% url sportdub.views.login %}">
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="span8"/>
  <input type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one onclick call in ur submit button with **return**...  Your code should be,

```
<form  method="post" action="{% url sportdub.views.login %}">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" class="span8"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick = "return isValidEmailAddress();"></button>
  </form>

function isValidEmailAddress() {
     var emailAddress = $('#email').val();
     var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
     return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  };
```

Comment: Please add the validation to the onsubmit of the form rather than the onclick of the button also you are not passing the address

Comment: Using the click handler on the buttonis a bad idea - it will not fire when the form is submitted by pressing enter in the text field.